# Drawing cube in OpenGL. Shorter code with iteration, but doesn't work

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm new to OpenGL. I've successfully drawn cubes, and tried to improve the code, came up with this, but this only draws the first face of the cube:

```
glPushMatrix();
glColor3d(1,0,0);
glRotatef(45,0,1,0);
glTranslatef(0,0,3);

for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
   glBegin(GL_QUADS);
   glVertex3f(0,0,0);
   glVertex3f(3,0,0);
   glVertex3f(3,3,0);
   glVertex3f(0,3,0);
   glEnd();
   if(i<4)
    glRotatef(90,0,1,0);
   if(i=4)
    glRotatef(90,1,0,0);
   if(i=5)
    glRotatef(180,1,0,0);
}

glRotatef(90,1,0,0);

glPopMatrix();
```

The iteration doesn't seem to work at all! Am I missing something basic about the way how OpenGL works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First answer is: You're using an archaic version of OpenGL. Nowadays you don't send vertices one by one, but instead:

- create a memory buffer with some vertices
- send that buffer to a buffer (VBO) in the GPU memory
- render directly from there using `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements`.

Try it sometime, works drastically faster :-)

---

And on what's wrong with your example- Did you perhaps mean this...?

```
if (i == 4)
```

and

```
if (i == 5)
```

Please enable your compiler warnings so that you'll catch that. (I didn't see it either, by the way - my compiler did :-))

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that once rotation is over, you have to translate on z-axis, draw the quad, and then translate back to the original point.

The general approach for what you are trying would be:

```
glPushMatrix();

<initial-setup>

for i = 0 to 5
    translate on z-axis +(width/2) units
    draw the quad
    translate on z-azis -(width/2) units
    if i<=3
        rotate 90 about y-axis
    elif i == 4
        rotate 90 about x-axis
    else
        rotate 180 about x-axis
glPopMatrix();
```

And as @kos correctly pointed out, replace `if(i=4)` by `if (i==4)` and similar for next statement.